# excess intersection theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Can the excess intersection theory be applied to the following problem:

I have a non-singular irreducible variety $X$ of dimension $k$ and degree $d$ and $k+1$ hyperplane sections of $X$, $H_1,H_2,\ldots,H_{k+1}$ such that $\cap _{j}H_j$ is not empty, as expected, but is a finite set of points $\Sigma$. Is there a way to find the degree of $\Sigma$ (that is the number of points?).

Comment: I doubt it.  What can you tell us about your variety $X$?  Is it linearly nondegenerate?

Comment: $X$ is the Segre variety product of $k$ lines.

Comment: For your variety, the number of points contained in $\Sigma$ can vary from $1$ up to, at least, $2^k-k-1$.  So I do not see how an excess intersection theory computation will lead to so many different answers.  Do you have some extra information about the hyperplane sections in your case of interest?

Comment: No, I don't. And I know that for $k>3$, there are linear sections of codimension $k+1$ with more than $2^k-k-1$ points. Do you have any suggestion how I can tackle this problem?

Comment: I think that intersection theory can help when I have a linear section of codimension $k$ that intersects $X$ in a curve $C$ and a finite set of points $\Gamma$. To get $|\Gamma|$ how much should I know about $C$?

Comment: Well, because it is what I know (not because I think it is a likely approach), I would specialize to the normal cone of the locus parameterizing "large intersections".  For every point $p=(p_1,\dots,p_k)$ in $X = (\mathbb{P}^1)^k$, there is a codimension $k+1$ linear section $X\cap L_p$ that is a union $\cup_{i<j} Z_{i,j}$, where $Z_{i,j}$ parameterizes points $(q_1,\dots,q_n)$ such that $(q_i,q_j)$ equals $(p_i,p_j)$.  Inside the Grassmannian parameterizing linear subspaces, I would consider the deformation to the copy of $X$ parameterizing these subspaces $L_p$.

Comment: 1st question: imagine k general hypersurfaces meeting X in d points, and one more meeting r of those points - I don't see how one could possibly compute r from this data. 2nd question: you should at least know degree C. see Fulton ex.12.3.1, p.223. (refined Bezout) –